# Is using Salesforce's Data.com email addresses considered CAN-SPAM compliant?

Tags: email, pardot

A company I know has purchased thousands of email addresses through Salesforce Data Prospector ( https://www.salesforce.com/products/data/solutions/ ).  They've now received a complaint through Pardot and the Salesforce Pardot team is considering taking action to disable the Pardot account.  I was under the impression that both buying and selling email addresses was illegal under CAN-SPAM law.  How can Salesforce Data even offer Prospector as a service legally and is the selling of email address lists allowed under CAN-SPAM?  Salesforce seems to be selling a product they know to be in violation of their own terms & conditions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question appears to be soliciting opinions. Instead it should be asked on the Success Community where it can be responded to by Salesforce employees or others with product specific knowledge who can assist with actually solving or addressing the issue.

Comment: Where is the Success Community exactly on StackExchange?  Thank you

Comment: It's not on StackExchange. It's at https://success.salesforce.com.

Comment: In addition to answer below - The acquirer needs to use responsibly and follow all applicable laws. Bad analogy, Alcohol is Legal (here) I can buy it but as soon as I give it to a minor, or use it and drive, ...or insert example here..., I just broke the law...

Comment: Thanks Eric - For the record I'm not trying to solicit any opinion in any way whatsoever.  I am however trying to get a direct, explicit answer to the question: Is using Salesforce's Data.com service legal in terms of using to send emails?  That's all.  Pretty simple.  I'd like a very clear explanation as to why this is off-topic.  @crmprogdev was extremely vague.  How is a direct Salesforce legality question opinion oriented?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, no it is not CAN-SPAM compliant because the emails were not obtained by the sending company ( pretty straight forward ).  Instead they were purchased from Salesforce.com where it's generally unlikely that there's any overlap of the existing customer base or opt-in lists.

In terms of legality of selling the addresses they are partially legally covered by this notice / license information:  https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150M0000038OwQQAU

Relevant quote:

> "Important: Data.com Data provided to customers via the Data.com
>   Services may not be used for any purpose which:
>   * Relates to establishing
>   * Violates applicable law or which is related to generating or facilitating unsolicited commercial email (spam), for example in
>   violation of the U.S. CAN-SPAM Act or any other applicable anti-spam
>   law"

It's possible an email address is in a purchased list that should not be there because it was obtained improperly, but that would be a Salesforce.com liability, potentially detected by means of a spamtrap such as https://www.projecthoneypot.org

Comment: beat me to it :)